# Why Mac OS X Bash || (double pipe) operator doesn't work?

Tags: macos, bash

I made a bash script in Mac OS X like the below one.

```
pidof asdf || echo "not exist"
```

and I expect "not exist" as the output (because pid asdf does not exist),
but it was not working normally (reversed).

I tried on my Linux machine and I got the output "not exist".

Does anyone know why OS X works in reverse from Linux?

Comment: How is `pidof` implemented?  It isn't standard (or, at least, isn't in my environment on Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan).

Comment: What does "it was not working normally (reversed)" even mean?

Comment: i mean difference with linux.

Comment: in case of linux A || B  => if A true then, do B
in case of osx A && B => if A true then, do B

Comment: Totally insane claim. For `A || B`, `B` is only executed when `A` fails with nonzero status, otherwise `B` is short-circuited. It's the same in every POSIX shell (and every sane language, particularly the C family).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Pidof is used in linux: http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof

Comment: @fedorqui What do you even mean? You *should* get `23` (and an error saying `pidof` not found) because `pidof` doesn't even exist on a standard OS X install. What do you expect otherwise?

Comment: Oh and of course you should also get `23` on Linux since `pidof randomstring` would also fail, due to the non-existing process name.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: I know that `pidof` is available on Linux.  I did a Google search with the term 'pidof command not found mac' and came up with a variety of implementations for Mac.  And the variety means the implementation could be important.  The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command, so if the filtering of the output is done by something that exits with a zero status, the behaviour could be different on Mac and Linux.  On Ubuntu, `/bin/pidof` is a symlink to `/sbin/killall5`.  Mac OS X has `/usr/bin/killall`; it may help.

Comment: I installed pidof by homebrew. (i just know),
I checked exit status of pidof command in Mac OS X. it returned always 0.
thank you for you guys answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It did help the OP.